# How can i send my password using Python module Subprocess?

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I'm a rookie in Python.
My goal is to build scripts on Python to work with VPS. I found some information about subprocess module and try to use it like this:

```
import subprocess

IP = '***'
PASS = '***'

subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "root@"+IP])
```

But I am stuck with sending password.
How can I make this?
Thanks in advance.